# Sphinx autodoc doesn't recognize a TypedDict key with the name "values"

Tags: python, dictionary, python-sphinx, autodoc, typeddict

Say that I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import TypedDict

class Signal(TypedDict):
    """My signal."""

    name: str  #: Signal name.
    values: np.ndarray  #: Signal values.
    signal_unit: str  #: Signal unit.
    sampling_period: float  #: Signal sampling period.
    time_unit: str  #: Signal sampling period.
```

When I run `sphinx-apidoc -f -n -o ./source ../src/mypackage/` and then `run html` the code is correctly rendered but for the `np.ndarray` type.
Any idea on how I can fix this?

Let me know if you need more info.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change `values` to something else, for example `value`?

Comment: It actually worked. But I cannot change all the codebase + the tests, and also `values` is more appropriate than `value`. Is there any workaround for using `values` or is it worth opening an issue on `sphinx-autodoc` issue tracker?

Comment: I think the problem is that a key named `values` clashes with the `values` dictionary method. I cannot think of a workaround other than renaming the key.

Comment: Indeed. `values()` is a method of `dict` and `typeddict` is essentially a `dict`. 
Nevertheless, `dict` differentiate between the attribute `values` and the method  `values()` but `sphinx-autdoc` won't. Is it a bug or it is OK and I have to find another solution? Calling the values of a signal with another name... is weird though.

Comment: Possible solutions: A) add values in the `docstring` instead of letting `autodoc` to parse the code only for this attribute; C) Change datatype and use e.g. `namedtuple` or `dataclass`. Other suggestions are more than welcome. :)